# execution plan suggesting to add an index on columns which are not part of where clause

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-execution-plan, non-clustered-index

I am running following query in SSMS and execution plan suggesting to add index on columns which are not part of where clause. I was planning to add index on two columns which are being used in where clause (OID and TransactionDate).

```
SELECT  
        [OID] , //this is not a PK. Primary key column is not a part of sql script
        [CustomerNum] ,
        [Amount] ,
        [TransactionDate] ,
        [CreatedDate] 

FROM    [dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE   OID = 489
        AND TransactionDate > '01/01/2018 06:13:06.46';
```

Index suggestion

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Transaction] ([OID],[TransactionDate])
INCLUDE ([CustomerNum],[Amount],[CreatedDate])
```

**Updated**

Do i need to include other columns? Data is being imported to that table through a back end process using SQLBulkCopy class in .net. I am wondering if having non cluster index on all columns would reduce the performance. (In my table is Pk column called TransactionID which is not needed but i have this in the table in case its needed in the future otherwise SQLBulkCopy works better with heap. Other option is to drop and recreate indexes before and after SQLBulkCopy operation)

[image]

Comment: Can you add the execution plan? How many records get returned?

Comment: I have added few more info on my question. Table has 1 million rows and 455 records are returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `INCLUDE` keyword specifies the non-key columns to be added to the leaf level of the nonclustered index.

This means that if you will add this index and run the query again, SQL Server can get all the information needed from the index, thus eliminating the need to perform a lookup in the table as well.

As a general rule of thumb - when SSMS suggest an index, create it. You can always drop it later if it doesn't help.

Comment: I don't see how that information impacts my answer. To improve the speed of this query, add the index as suggested. If you want to, you can drop and recreate it after the bulk copy, but unless you are recreating the index offline (meaning, the user doesn't have to sit and wait for it to complete), it will probably not improve performance of the entire transaction (drop, copy, recreate).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add all table columns in your non-clustered index, suggested index is good for the query provided. SQL Server database engine suggestions are usually really good.

INCLUDE keyword is required to avoid KEY LOOKUP and use NONCLUSTERED INDEX SEEK.

All in all: No NONCLUSTERED INDEX results in Clustered index scan

Created NONCLUSTERED INDEX with no included columns results in NONCLUSTERED INDEX scan plus key lookup.

Created NONCLUSTERED INDEX with included columns results in NONCLUSTERED INDEX SEEK.